# How to properly display HDR image on Android with supported display

Tags: images, hdr

I have found some documentation ([HDR Video Playback](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/hdr)) how to display HDV video content on HDR-supported phones. But how to display HDR image (16bit PNG or EXR or create HDR content Bitmap and display) ?

The only one information I have found is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config#RGBA_F16).

Comment: Hello 404pio. Are you asking this question as a developer or as an end-user? Developer/programming oriented questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Mainly as a developer - so this question should be closed. But partially as an end-user - so we do not need to close:)

Comment: I'm a bit curious about what it means by "showing HDR image"? An image is a static object, so it's displayed as-is on the image reader. Also, HDR is usually done on post-processing, so the final image is just a static image with common formats (e.g. PNG, JPG, etc.)... unless you mean to mix multiple images with different exposure to achieve HDR? Otherwise, some image editors (like Google's Snapseed) have a feature to simulate HDR with its own algorithm.

Comment: HDR is large topic. Let's say that I have already HDR image (I do not care from where it is - google app or highend camera). I want to display it as good as device can. So the device and the application should read image to 16-bit depth data and metadata to use proper color transfer characteristic, color primaries, colorspace, color_range (like in videos)